# Added Form to WPF looks horrible

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, forms, button

I have added a form to a WPF project as a settings dialog. I have text boxes set to 3d border and buttons set to standard appearance. This is my result.

[image]

Is there a reason why the form inside a WPF is rendering like this?

Comment: WPF uses custom styles like java's swing

Comment: This screenshot is from a window form added into a WPF project

Comment: Bad idea. Likely it falls bac kto Default look, no manifest (Which you can fix) but therte is no reason to use a Windows form in a WPF application. What about you make a - Attention - WPF FORM?

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with it. I think you should re-make the form in WPF regardless unless there is a really important reason you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the **App.xaml.cs** of your project and override the **OnStartup** method of the **App** class. So your **App** class should look like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    }
}
```

this should make your **forms** look better in your WPF application.